# Fade in and fade out animation is too slow

Tags: ios, fadein, fadeout, uiviewanimation

I made an animation, fade in and fade out on a cell. When I press the cell(a button on the entire cell) the action is delegate via a protocol on a collectionView and pops to another controller (detailController).

The cell

```
 - (IBAction)cellButtonPressed:(id)sender {
    [self fadeIn];
}

-(void)fadeIn {
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5
                          delay:0.0
                        options:0.0
                     animations:^{
                         self.coverAlbumPhoto.alpha = 0.0f;
                         self.shadowView.alpha = 0.0f;
                         self.mountainBorderImageView.alpha = 0.0f;

                     } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                         [self fadeOut];
                     }];
}
-(void)fadeOut {
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5
                          delay:0.0
                        options:0.0
                     animations:^{
                         self.coverAlbumPhoto.alpha = 1.0f;
                         self.shadowView.alpha = 1.0f;
                         self.mountainBorderImageView.alpha = 1.0f;

                     } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                         if ([self.delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(tapCellButtonAtIndexPath:)]) {
                             [self.delegate tapCellButtonAtIndexPath:self.indexPath];
                         }
                     }];
}
```

Collection View

```
(void)tapCellButtonAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    ArtworkModel *artworkModel = (ArtworkModel *)[listOfArtworks objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    FBWorkDetailsViewController *dvc = [[FBWorkDetailsViewController alloc] initWithArtwork:artworkModel];
    FBLeftMenuViewController *left = [[FBLeftMenuViewController alloc] init];
    MFSideMenuContainerViewController *container = [MFSideMenuContainerViewController
                                                    containerWithCenterViewController: dvc
                                                    leftMenuViewController: left
                                                    rightMenuViewController:nil
                                                    withHeader: YES];
    [container.titleLabel setText:@"WORK DETAILS"];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController: container animated: YES];
}
```

The problem is that the animation is TOO SLOW. Can anybody explain me why? Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You have 2 animations, each with a duration of .5 seconds. That gives a total duration of 1 second. If you want it to be faster, use shorter durations. A total animation time of .2 to .3 seconds is probably a good place to start, so try backing down the duration of each step to 0.15 seconds (0.3 seconds total).